# How to import a file in another folder

Tags: python

recently I have been making a python project, but my files were too messy and I decided to group my files into folders. However, I am now struggling to import a file from another directory/folder

My code:

```
# Imports
import random, math
# Import from my files
import info/information.py
x = 1
while x < 10000:
    x += 1
info/information.quit("It took {} seconds for python to count to 10000")
```

In information.py:

```
import sys, time
start = time.time()

def quit(txt: str="Finished code with runtime {} seconds"):
    if "{" in txt and "}" in txt:
        try:
            print(txt.format(round(time.time() - start, 1)))
            sys.exit()
        except KeyError:
            raise KeyError("Please put nothing inbetween the \"{\" and the \"}\"")
    else:
        raise SyntaxError("Need to include \"{}\"!")
```

My error:

```
File "d:/Entertainment/Coding/Python/Pygame/BUG WORLD/main.py", line 6
    import modules/information
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I need help with this. Thanks in advance

Comment: `import info/information.py` should be `import info.information`. and there should be an `__init__.py` file in the `info` directory. and the `PYTHONPATH` should be set correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To manage imports in my project, I usually follow the below approach:

```
main.py
info
|----- information.py
|----- __init__.py
```

contents of `__init__.py`:

```
from . import information
#other module import if present
```

Code for `information.py` remains unchanged:

```
import sys, time
start = time.time()

def quit(txt: str="Finished code with runtime {} seconds"):
    if "{" in txt and "}" in txt:
        try:
            print(txt.format(round(time.time() - start, 1)))
            sys.exit()
        except KeyError:
            raise KeyError("Please put nothing inbetween the \"{\" and the \"}\"")
    else:
        raise SyntaxError("Need to include \"{}\"!")
```

Then you can import your modules in `main.py` like this:

```
import info
# info.information is accessible
# info.information.quit()
...
```

It might be a overdo for this case, since you have a single module but helps as your project size grows.

Answer (score 0):

You should use import info.information, to acess directory *info* and then import module information.

Answer (score 0):

You should try it like that.

```
# Imports
import random, math
# Import from my files
from info.information import quit
x = 1
while x < 10000:
    x += 1
quit("It took {} seconds for python to count to 10000")
```

Please notice you can also add the folder to your PYTHONPATH environment variable

```
sys.path.append('/full/path/to/application/app/folder')
```